# Does AdminDirectory.Users.list support query with showDeleted=true?

Tags: google-admin-sdk

I'm trying to retrieve data for a deleted user (in order to undelete it) in this way:

```
  var users = AdminDirectory.Users.list({
    domain: 'mydomain.com',
    showDeleted: 'true',
    query: 'email=name.surname@mydomain.com'
  });
```

query parameter seems to be ignored: this code returns a list of all deleted users, while if I run the same code for active users (no showDeleted:'true', and email of active user) it returns the user's email address as expected

am I missing anything? or is this the default behavior when showDeleted:'true' is used?

thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Looks like the behavior you are describing might in fact be a bug.

Because of this, I have taken the opportunity to file a report on Google's Issue Tracker [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/197620570). I suggest you star the issue as all the updates will be posted there.